# If my PC doesn't "turn on" randomly, what is that a sign of?

Tags: boot, power-supply, hardware-failure, power

2.7 years ago, I bought a HP Z240 tower workstation PC.

Recently, I have begun noticing that, when I press the power button in the morning, it doesn't "fully power on", or something similar. The power LED indicator is lit, and I can hear it spinning up, but the monitor appears to not get a video signal and soon falls back to some powersaving mode.

Then I press the power button again to turn it off, and then immediately (perhaps one second of waiting) press it once more. Now it powers on *and* gives a video signal to the monitor, with zero other changes.

Of course, this cannot be a good sign. But what exactly is falling apart? The PSU? The video cable doesn't seem like it is flimsy; at first, I tried to adjust it, thinking that it had somehow unplugged. But it doesn't seem to be the case.

It's as if it sometimes decides to boot up in some sort of "zombie state" where it doesn't fully "kick in".

It cannot possibly have anything to do with Windows, because I have a VeraCrypt password prompt before anything at all happens, in the "BIOS" or "UEFI" or whatever they call it these days. So when it works, which is most of the time, it shows the password prompt in the top-left corner.

What could be wrong? I told myself that I was "never" going to buy another computer after this, but if it's falling apart, I'm going to be forced to.

Comment: Are you sure your machine isn't going to sleep?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm extremely sure. It's fully powered off every time I turn it on. And all sleep/hibernation settings are completely disabled.

Comment: What OS are we dealing with exactly?

Comment: if "fully powered off" means power is removed from the PSU (e.g. the plug strip is switched off) then this can sometimes lead to a "double-post" situation where {magic configuration} happens. As to why this suddenly started, perhaps the CMOS battery is old.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot analyze the failure - you need a repair-shop for that.

It's possible that some connection is weak, and just by turning on
the computer the power is heating up the element, which expands,
thus improving the contact.

You may open up the computer and press all contacts, in the hope that
this will help. If not, use a repair-shop.

In any case, ensure that you have backups before starting.
Unencrypting your disk might also minimize the problem in case of a later
serious crash.

Comment: Not sending my computer to any kind of repair place. What do you mean by "press all contacts"? Inside? ... (And did you just suggest me to unencrypt my system? For real?)

Comment: @JLonghurst - Yes; The reason that suggestion is valid, is if the VeraCrypt header is lost, then all your data is gone.  But there are ways to reduce that risk without decrypting your data.

Comment: @JLonghurst Unless you're worried about somebody breaking into your house and stealing your disks, what's the problem with unencrypting your disks? As soon as you boot they are available for any software to access.

Comment: @doneal24 - Author types their VeraCrypt password.  Let's not suggest decrypting the drive, since that won't resolve the author's issue, of the machine not powering on.

Comment: @JLonghurst - I suspect harry is talking about the 24-pin motherboard connector (or whatever pin count HP uses).

Comment: @Ramhound Of course I have (encrypted) backups.

Comment: @doneal24 And yes, I am naturally worried about somebody breaking into my house and stealing my disks, as should any sensible person be. Note that this "somebody" can be somebody you know (or think you know), the government, etc.

Comment: @JLonghurst I always assume that NSA has access to my data no matter what protections I put in place. I usually don't think that I'm being targeted by other entities to try to get my gmail password

Comment: Re: contacts. I read this as "solder joint failure" and harrymc is suggesting the diagnostic method of pressing on individual mounted components (sometimes called "chopsticking" since chopsticks are handy and non-conductive)

Comment: FWIW: A computer that fails occasionally, for whatever reason, may stop working entirely "very soon now" (next minute, or next week; nobody can tell). My main advice is; DO a data backup NOW and make sure your backup is possible to restore (do a TEST!). THEN pick out the disk, and get it to someone who can analyze the problem. Assuming the problem isn't the disk itself.